# Can not resolve Error: .MixinName is undefined on line

Tags: web, less, .net-6.0

when I'm running my .net6.0 web project I get numerous errors about undefined mixins.

I tried many things but still can not fix this error.

Here is some more information about the project that can be useful:

- All .less file names stat with underscore "_".
- All .less files are imported to styles.less file.
- I import the file with the mixins like this: @import "../_mixins.less";
- When calling a mixins always doing like this: .mixin-name();
- In Index.cshtml file I have link with the compiled css:
- In the Statup.cs I configure the service like this:

```
services.AddWebOptimizer(pipe =>
{
    pipe.AddLessBundle("/css/styles.min.css", "css/**/*.less")
        .MinifyCss();
}
```